# count the sequence that has the max sum in array O(N)

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

if i want to count the sequence in the arrays that has the max sum, how can I do it when I have a limit of O(n) time complexity ?

For example : {1,2,3,4,-3} the output will be 4 because the sum of 1+2+3+4 is the maximum sum and there are 4 numbers in that sequence

I know how to do it with O(N^2) time complexity but not with O(n) help ? :)

Comment: If you had the sequence of the sums up until that point in the original sequence, would you be able to solve it then? For example: {1,2,3,4,-3} as original sequence would yield: {1,3,6,10,7}. You can get from the original one to the summed sequence in O(n) time. Now from the summed one to the length of the max sequence in O(n) as well..

Comment: What is the output if there are several such subarrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can to iterate like this :

```
MaxSum = 0;
CurrentSum = 0;
MaxLen = 0;
CurrentLen = 0;

Index = GetFirstPositiveValue(); 
// This function returns the first Index where Array[Index] > 0
// O(n) 

while (Index < Array.Length()) {
    // general loop to parse the whole array
    while (Array[Index] > 0 && Index < Array.Length()) {
        CurrentSum += Array[Index];
        CurrentLen++;
        Index++
    }
    // We computed a sum of positive integer, we store the values 
    // if it is higher than the current max
    if (CurrentSum > MaxSum) {
        MaxSum = CurrentSum;
        MaxLen = CurrentLen;
    }
    // We reset the current values only if we get to a negative sum
    while (Array[Index] < 0 && Index < Array.Length()) {
        CurrentSum += Array[Index];
        CurrentLen++;
        Index++;
    }
    //We encountered a positive value. We check if we need to reset the current sum
    if (CurrentSum < 0) {
        CurrentSum = 0;
        CurrentLen = 0;
    }
}
// At this point, MaxLen is what you want, and we only went through 
// the array once in the while loop.
```

Start on the first positive element. If every element is negative, then just pick the highest and the problem is over, this is a 1 element sequence.

We keep on summing as long as we have positive values, so we have a current max value. When we have a negative, we check if the current max is higher than the stored max. If so, we replace the stored max and sequence length by the new values.

Now, we sum negative numbers. When we find another positive, we have to check something :

If the current sum is positive, then we can still have a max sum with this sequence. If it's negative, then we can throw the current sum away, because the max sum won't contain it :

In {1,-2,3,4}, 3+4 is greater than 1-2+3+4

As long as we haven't been through the entire array, we restart this process. We only reset the sequence when we have a subsequence generating a negative sum, and we store the max values only if we have a greater value.

I think this works as intended, and we only go through the array one or two times. So it's O(n)

I hope that's understandable, I have trouble making my thoughts clear. Executing this algorithm with small examples such as {1,2,3,-4,5} / {1,2,3,-50,5} / {1,2,3,-50,4,5} may help if I'm not clear enough :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know the maximum sum of a subarray at the end of an array of length N, you can trivially calculate it for one of length N+1:

```
[..., X]       has max subsum S
[..., X, Y]    has max subsum max(0, S + Y)
```

since either you include Y or you have an empty subarray (since the subarray is at the end of the list).

You can find all maximum sums for subarrays ending at *any* position by building this from an empty list:

```
[]             S = 0
[1]            S = 1
[1, 2]         S = 3
[1, 2, -4]     S = 0
[1, 2, -4, 5]  S = 5
```

You then only need to keep track of the maximum and its width. Here is some Python code demonstrating the algorithm.

```
def ranges(values):
    width = cum_sum = 0

    for value in values:
        cum_sum += value
        width += 1

        if cum_sum < 0:
            width = cum_sum = 0

        yield (cum_sum, width)

total, width = max(ranges([-2, 1, 2, 3, -8, 4, -3]))

total, width
#>>> (6, 3)
```